# Have more than one Pin Annotation? MapKit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotation

At the moment I have 1 pin, when you tap the pin it displays information. However I want more than 1 pin at different locations. How would I do this?

This is my code.

Map.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 52.509078;
    region.center.longitude = -1.884799;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"AVFC";
    ann.subtitle = @"Aston Villa Football Club";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

NewClass.h

```
@interface NewClass : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;

    NSString *titleOne;
    NSString *subtitleTwo;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *titleOne;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitleTwo;
@end
```

Comment: Try taking a look here, it's a good tutorial on getting started with MapKit, including Annotations:http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your annotations (however many you want) then add them to an `NSArray`. You can add them to your `MKMapView` using `[mapview addAnnotations:annotationArray];`

[MKMapView Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Comment: Which part are you confused about?